# error when vim macro recording play

Tags: vim, macros

I know how to record a macro use vim.
eg. record macro a:
in normal mode, 
qa start recording,
do some action,
q stop recording.

---

If I want to play it, I can use @a.
Now I want to play 10 times,  10@a should be work, 
But for me,  It isn't work, It just play in one line.

why?  what should i do to get 10@a work?

---

Just like follow:

```
include <stdio.h>
include <string.h>
include <stdlib.h>
include <unistd.h>
include <my.h>
```

I want to add "#" at every line, so recode macro a in the first line,
then go down the second line,  do the action 4@a.  But wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
####include <string.h>
include <stdlib.h>
include <unistd.h>
include <my.h>
```

Comment: To add `#` to  x lines, use `ctrl + v` and `I` to insert your text and hit `Esc` when done. This will write the same on all lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the movement command (probably <kbd>j</kbd> in your case) in the macro. So record your macro as

<kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

And then play it with <kbd>4</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

Comment: OK,  thanks.    Before I find a replacement : visual mode, choose follow lines; then   do command  :normal @a.  Any way,  4@a is more easy.